# Printing from Virtualbox, terminal

Tags: virtualbox

First. I'm NOT a superuser, at all.
I.v been googled and tested severals commands but cant find my printer from guest

I running Ubuntu 17.10 and Win 7 in Virtualbox 5.1.30

My printer is a HP USB connected in host and work fine ther. 
As a guest i Cant find the printer at all.

It worked fine before changing Hardware. 
Ubuntu and VM is reinnstalled. VM is started on old .VDI file.

Help... somone :/

Comment: Does the VM have access to the host's USB ports?

Comment: I can find the Printer if i hatch the USB.
But it seems like i ned to innstall it then, if i do VM takes over the printer and it wont work from Ubuntu.. ?

Comment: Yes you will need to install in in Windows. I believe only one OS can control the USB port at a time, so as long as the VM is running you can't print from Ubuntu. I am not sure about that though.

Comment: Damn. I use Win in work but dont like it so use Ubuntu else.
Before i could use the printer in both, then i had XP innstalled.

Comment: You can use it as a network printer then. Let Ubuntu control the USB, share the printer over the "network", and find the network printer in Windows.

Comment: I tryed severals guide for this but cant figured it out.